# Un-clickable sidebar links on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar on my website that contains link's to individual divs, but when I try and click on any of them they just highlight without jumping to the div.

The website in question is http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/dip/pages/football.html

the top nav works fine, it's just the side nav that seems to have problems.

Sidebar nav

```
<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#intro">Football</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked text-center">
      <li><a href="#times">Men's Training</a></li>
      <li><a href="#times2">Women's Training</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>

  </div>
  </div>
```

example div

```
  <div class="col-md-9" id="intro">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>some text </p>

                    </div>
            </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to make anchors?

Comment: Well, I want each link to jump to a different div on the page, so the brand is linked to the intro on the page, the coach link jumps to the 'coach' div and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your **smoothscroll.js** in path styling/js delete all and paste this to **JUMP** directly

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
    var hashtag=$(this).attr("href"); 
    window.location=hashtag;

    });

    });
```

EDIT:

try to put this on smoothscroll.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {

    jQuery('#main').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);

    return false;

    e.preventDefault();

});

});
```

this is the problem: `('html,body')` you want to scroll the main div

Comment: Sorry i wasn't specific enough, I want it to smooth scroll to each div, not just jump, that does however, make it jump to the div, which is better than it not doing anything at all.

Comment: see the edit, in this line  `var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;` set the margin if cover the text, to fix try like this  `var targetOffset = $target.offset().top-60;`

Comment: It's still just jumping from one div to another :/

Comment: change  `jQuery('html,body')` into  `jQuery('#main')` in your actual code

Comment: see, another time,my last edit in the answer, copy the script and paste into smoothscroll.js.

Comment: Woo! you've fixed the problem. It's now got a weird bouncing effect though, where if i click the same link twice it scrolls back to where it was. i suspect this is to do with the toggleclass i have set up for the sidebar inside the html

Comment: don't forget the check